# How to read SQL database specific row text from another row value

Tags: asp.net, sql, database

I am trying to query data of a specific column text from another column.

Basically, I have a Supplier Database that has a SupplierID and Country column.

I already have the SupplierID for that specific row for example, it is 14. I would like to get the text value of Country column based on the 14 value.

The Supplier ID I am getting by the following code (listbox):

```
<asp:ListBox ID="SupplierListBox" runat="server" 
            DataSourceID="SupplierCompanyDataSource" DataTextField="Company" 
            DataValueField="SupplierID" Width="315px" 
            Height="80px" 
            onselectedindexchanged="SupplierListBox_SelectedIndexChanged" 
            AutoPostBack="True"></asp:ListBox>
```

Code:

```
        string SupplierListvalue = SupplierListBox.SelectedItem.Value; //SupplierListvalue retrieves the SupplierID value

        SqlDataReader rdr = null;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=ROG;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Country from SupplierDB", conn);
        cmd.Connection = conn;

        conn.Open();
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            TextBox1.Text = rdr["Country"].ToString();
            MessageBox.Show("Connection Successful");
            MessageBox.Show(rdr.ToString());
        }

        conn.Close();
```

Comment: Have you tried `"SELECT country FROM myTable WHERE SupplierID=14"`?

Comment: You're trying to _query data_? What rdbms are you using, how do you want to query it(ADO.NET,Entity-Framework,Linq-To-Sql,.....) and finally, what have you already tried?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Your method was correct. I had to use the following command:

`SelectCommand="SELECT [Company], [SupplierID] FROM [SupplierDB] WHERE ([SupplierID] &gt;= @SupplierID)">
<SelectParameters><asp:Parameter DefaultValue="14" Name="SupplierID" Type="Int32" /> //defaultvalue="14" is the starting value in the database

SelectCommand="SELECT [SupplierID], [Country] FROM [SupplierDB] WHERE ([SupplierID] = @SupplierID)">
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="SupplierListBox" Name="SupplierID"                PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's not clear what's the main problem, so i'll show you a working example which selects the `Country` column from database with ADO.NET, uses Parameters to avoid SQL-Injection and `using`-statement to ensure that all unmanaged resources as the connection get disposed(closed).

```
string sql = @"
            SELECT Country
            FROM dbo.Supplier
            WHERE SupplierID = @SupplierId";
using (var con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=ROG;Integrated Security=True"))
{
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@SupplierId", SqlDbType.Int);
        cmd.Parameters["@SupplierId"].Value = int.Parse(SupplierListBox.SelectedItem.Value);
        using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (rdr.Read())
            {
                TextBox1.Text = rdr.GetString(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into using parameterized queries.  Try this out:

```
    string SupplierListvalue = SupplierListBox.SelectedItem.Value; //SupplierListvalue retrieves the SupplierID value
    ...
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Country from SupplierDB WHERE SupplierID = @supplierId", conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@supplierId", SupplierListvalue);
    ...
```

Good luck.

Comment: `string SupplierListvalue = SupplierListBox.SelectedItem.Value;
            MessageBox.Show(SupplierListvalue.ToString());            
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=ROG;Integrated Security=True");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Country] FROM [SupplierDB] WHERE [SupplierID] = @SupplierID", conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SupplierID", SupplierListvalue.ToString());`

Still not able to get the Country text based on Supplierlistvalue. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I was approaching it in the wrong way. Basically the following was the correct code:

`<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SupplierCompanyDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ROGConnectionString %>"

SelectCommand="SELECT [Company], [SupplierID] FROM [SupplierDB] WHERE ([SupplierID] &gt;= @SupplierID)">
<SelectParameters>
<asp:Parameter DefaultValue="14" Name="SupplierID" Type="Int32" /></SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>`

`<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SupplierCountryDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ROGConnectionString %>" 
SelectCommand="SELECT [SupplierID], [Country] FROM [SupplierDB] WHERE ([SupplierID] = @SupplierID)">
<SelectParameters> <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="SupplierListBox" Name="SupplierID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" /></SelectParameters></asp:SqlDataSource>`

This does the job! So now when I click on the listbox1 the listbox2 also gets clicked similar to cascading.